# How can a google script be applied to alternate rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is for the script to apply to Even rows so that I can use the Odd rows for other input. I have attempted to apply a specific range to the function, but my many, many attempts have simply borked the script.

As it stands everything works fine with this code, but it applies the script to everything.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if (wsName === mainWsName && c === Category && r > 3){
    OptionsValidation (val,r);
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete with terms undefined.  It's not a [MCVE].

Comment: If you want to only respond to even rows and you only want to perform the function on Sheet1 then start your code with this: `function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.rowStart%2==1 || sh.getName()!='Sheet1') return;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is filter out the odd rows:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  if (r % 2 == 1) return; //THIS ENDS THE SCRIPT WITHOUT DOING ANYTHING IF ODD
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if (wsName === mainWsName && c === Category && r > 3){
    OptionsValidation (val,r);
```

Comment: You might find it useful to checkout the available information in the event object. Look for terms like columnStart, columnEnd, rowStart, rowEnd, e.value ... etc